# help about place of header file in C

Tags: c, include, header-files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [#include in .h or .c / .cpp ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002110/include-in-h-or-c-cpp)

Can anyone explain to me the difference between including a C header file in another header file or C source file in C ? How can the placement of header file includes affect code in the C language ?

Comment: Numerous duplicates, e.g. [#include in .h or .c / .cpp ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002110/include-in-h-or-c-cpp) and [Where to put include statements, header or source?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943352/where-to-put-include-statements-header-or-source)

Comment: **Welcome to StackOverflow!** Please, before asking a question, **search** if it has already been asked/answered. Thanks! Regards.

Answer (score 3):

It is considered good practice not to include any header files in your header files that you don't absolutely need to for the signatures of your functions (a form of hiding unnecessary details).

That said, any header file included in your header file will also be included in your source file, as the source file includes your header file (typing this is getting confusing :) ).

Answer (score 1):

This might not be an easily answered question, since it influences your code design and propably the performance of your compilation.

First of, header files are read sequentially, so in the following example `first.h` would be read before `second.h`.

```
#include "first.h"
#include "second.h"
```

That means, that any definitions stated in `first.h` are also defined while reading `second.h`. Consider the following example:

In `first.h` the following is defined:

```
#define SOME_VERY_IMPORTANT_DEFINE
```

now if the `second.h` is read, see the following code:

```
#ifndef SOME_VERY_IMPORTANT_DEFINE
#include "third.h"
#endif
```

the `third.h` will not be included in your code, because `SOME_VERY_IMPORTANT_DEFINE` is defined and the conditional resolves to false.

Also, inclusions of header files are hierarchically, so all headers included in a header file, are also included in the source file that includes the header.

This is often used to provide an easy start into a library without having to scratch your head, which headers you need, because there is one header that includes all others.

I hope this helped a bit :)

Comment: thank you for helps,I understood definitely that you had said

Answer (score 1):

Just understand that preprocessor is going to copy the headers to the source files if included  and only sources files get compiled.